# Load data in AppDelegate, but can not access later in UIView? What's wrong?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I create a new "View-based Application" project and modify the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method as follow.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    downloader = [[InternetIOProcess alloc] init]; 
    [downloader initWithServer:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"] ];
    return YES;
}
```

InternetIOProcess is a `NSObject` with two variables, and a method:

```
@interface InternetIOProcess : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray* downloadingFile;
    NSURL* serverAddress;}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* downloadingFile;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSURL* serverAddress;
-(void) initWithServer:(NSURL*) server;
```

the implementation of InternetIOProcess is:

```
@implementation InternetIOProcess
@synthesize downloadingFile,serverAddress; //,serviceuploadingQueue,;
-(void) initWithServer:(NSURL*) server
{
    downloadingFile = [NSMutableArray array];
    serverAddress = server;
}
```

And then, I write a `IBAction` in `UIViewController` response to a button "touch up inside" event:

```
-(IBAction) test:(id)sender
{
    MyAppDelegate* d = (MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    InternetIOProcess* thedownloader = d.downloader;
    //value of "thedownloader" incorrect.
}
```

Try to access "thedownloader" here, its member "downloadingFile, serverAddress" both give random bad values!

Anybody know why can't I access this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies here with you not retaining the array and the server and bad naming convention of init. It looks like your custom init method is not getting called.

```
-(void) initWithServer:(NSURL*) server
{
    downloadingFile = [NSMutableArray array];
    serverAddress = server;
}
```

Try making the following changes

```
//InternetIOProcess.h add
-(id) initWithServer:(NSURL*) server;

//InternetIOProcess.m change
-(id) initWithServer:(NSURL*) server
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        downloadingFile = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
        serverAddress = [server retain];
    }
    return self;
}

//MyAppDelegate.m
downloader = [[InternetIOProcess alloc] initWithServer:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com"]];
```

Comment: The properties for the NSMutableArray are set to retain.  However, the initializer [NSMutableArray array] will return an object which is set for autorelease. I'd suggest not doing that and instead using the syntax: "[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]". Retain should be implied. The object in the delegate is never retained.

Comment: The downloader in the app delegate is automatically retained just by calling [InternetIOProcess alloc]. His initWithServer method needed to be called (based on the name) and retain the array and the serverAddress. [[NSMutableArray array] retain] and [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] would serve the same purpose here

Comment: Yes, but my point is it is redundant to call retain. Why is the downloader automatically retained? I don't see a property that sets retain or a retain call. alloc+init does not automatically retain. Agreed that init needed to change.

Comment: The way the code is displayed downloader is an instance variable. When you call alloc on any object that object immediately has retain value of 1 even if you do not call init. This line
downloader = [[InternetIOProcess alloc] init];
causes downloader to be retained in the app delegate

Comment: That doesn't mean it hasn't been recycled by the time you click on the button.  What I am getting at is that the instance is not explicitly marked retain. I can only assume that it is a property (with retain set), but if you see my original question this is what I was asking.

Comment: Yeah, both 'retain' and 'alloc+init' can Fix the problem! In addition, when did the two

Comment: In addition, I find the two members can be access before the end of "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions", so, does this means the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and the click action are two different threads, so the two member values are auto released before click action?

Comment: I could be wrong, but my understanding here is that they are both processed on the main thread (sequentually). The only way it would be processed on a separate thread would be if you split of the IBAction processing to a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Just checking, your UIViewController contains

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
```

and

```
#import "InternetIOProcess.h"
```

And your MyAppDelegate contains

```
#import "InternetIOProcess.h"
```

Also, are you getting any compiler warnings?

Answer (score 1):

Is downloader a property with the retain attribute on the delegate class? I don't see you specifying retain when you allocate the instance.

Answer (score 1):

In your initWithServer: method, use self.downloadingFile and self.serverAddress so that the objects are retained.